# HashMap<data class, data class> object.keySet() function throws error relating to a public call

Tags: java, hashmap, kotlin, hashset

I have a data class:

```
data class UniqueProtein(var id: String, var spc: Int, var r: DoubleArray)
```

I've created a `HashMap<UniqueProtein, UniqueProtein>` that I want to convert to a HashSet so I can find overlapping values between two HashMaps, like so:

```
dottest(control: HashMap<UniqueProtein, UniqueProtein>, treatment: HashMap<UniqueProtein, UniqueProtein>) 

var combineddata:HashSet<UniqueProtein> = control.keySet().retainAll(treatment.keySet())
```

IntelliJ is throwing the following in-line error under both keySet() calls:

```
is public /*package*/ in 'HashMap'
```

But since I've declared the object as a data class, I'm not sure what's going on...

Comment: So, you want to get back the keys of `control` as a set, that are also part of `treatment` as key?

Comment: Right - I'm looking for common UniqueProtein class objects between two collections.

Comment: Both answers below provide good solutions to the problem presented above: Dvarga opts for a functional programming call, and zsmb13 goes for the intersect method. I'll let the community decide which answer is worth the tick and come back to mark it as such a little later.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for the common keys in two maps, you can just [`intersect`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/intersect.html) their keys, like so:

```
val combinedData: Set<UniqueProtein> = control.keys.intersect(treatment.keys)
```

This returns a new set containing the common elements of the two sets.

---

And if you jump into its implementation, you'll see that it just uses [`retainAll`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/retain-all.html) (on a copy of the set that it's called on):

```
public infix fun <T> Iterable<T>.intersect(other: Iterable<T>): Set<T> {
    val set = this.toMutableSet()
    set.retainAll(other)
    return set
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the key set through the [`keys`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/keys.html) member instead.

Then to filter the keys that are part of the second map:

```
val combinedData = control.keys.filter { treatment.keys.contains(it) }.toSet()
```

To filter the whole map by keys (to get back the entries and not just the keys):

```
var filteredMapByKeys = control.filterKeys { treatment.keys.contains(it) }
```

To filter the values based by the keys:

```
var filteredValuesByKeys = control.filterKeys { treatment.keys.contains(it) }.values.toSet()
```

Comment: Got this one working. Thank you! Thanks for the alternative methods too